# Bitset operation in c++

Tags: c++, bitset

I am trying to pass bitset parameter to the below function but I am not able to:

> error: no matching function for call to search(std::bitset<100000000ul>&, int, unsigned int, unsigned int)

Here is the code:

```
#include <bitset>


#define ELEMENTS 100000000
#define TRANSITION_POINT 500
using namespace std;

template<unsigned int N>
unsigned int search(bitset<N> &array, int value, unsigned int low, unsigned int high)  {

      unsigned int middle;
      .........
}

int main()  {

    const unsigned int NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS = ELEMENTS;
    bitset<NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS> b;

    unsigned int i = 0;
    i = TRANSITION_POINT;
    while(i < NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS)  {

        b[i] = 1;
        i++;
    }

    pos = search(b, (int)1, (unsigned int)0, (unsigned int)NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS);
    return 1;
}
```

I tried to debug the code but couldnt find what is the problem. Could some one please help.

Comment: Works for me with MSVC++.  If you call search<ELEMENTS>(...) instead, you might get a better error message? (or that might compile for you?)

Comment: It compiles fine with GCC 4.5.2 (after declaring `pos`). Which compiler/version are you using?  (My suspicion is that in your compiler's `std::bitset<>`, the size parameter is an `unsigned long` - witnessed by the "ul" suffix in your error message - you should change your template to use `unsigned long` too).

Comment: Segfaults on gcc 4.4.3 at `bitset<NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS> b;`

Answer (score 6):

Your function template expects its first argument to be of type

```
std::bitset<(unsigned int)NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS>
```

but `b` is of type

```
std::bitset<(std::size_t)NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS>
```

This subtle difference means that argument-based type inference will fail to match your template (unless `std::size_t` happens to be an alias of `unsigned int`).

There are two ways to fix it:

- Change the parameter type of your template to `std::size_t` to match that of `std::bitset`
- Explicitly use the function template:
  `pos = search<NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS>(b, 1, 0, NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS);`

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine in my `g++` compiler. The only error I get is `'pos' is not declared in this scope`. (Also, I think its redundant to typecast to `int` and `unsigned int` while calling `search()`; that's not needed)

Answer (score 0):

With 32 bit gcc 4.4.3 here are the changes that were needed to make it not segfault:

```
#define ELEMENTS 10000000
```

Apparently there's a max size, because `100000000` caused it to segfault on `bitset<NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS> b;`

```
b.set(i,1);
```

The original `b[i] = 1` also caused a segfault.